# Selenium how to loop

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>http://www.theshop.com</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=img[alt=&quot;Theitem size 5&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Hi, how do I put a if else loop in. I want it to see if this item is available if it is to move to the next step and if not to go back to the start. Or it could refresh till the item becomes present then move ont to the next step. I`m only learning so apologies if i`m not making much sense.

Comment: If you need programming logic consider using one of the programming alternatives such as webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the [Selenium IDE Documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#sequence-of-evaluation-and-flow-control)

> Selenese, by itself, does not support condition statements (if-else, etc.) or iteration (for, while, etc.). Many useful tests can be conducted without flow control. However, for a functional test of dynamic content, possibly involving multiple pages, programming logic is often needed.
>
> When flow control is needed, there are three options:

```
 - Run the script using Selenium-RC and a client library such as Java or PHP to utilize the programming language’s flow control features.
 - Run a small JavaScript snippet from within the script using the storeEval command.
 - Install the goto_sel_ide.js extension.
```

Comment: Thanks all for taking the time to answer and helping me :-) Have installed the suggested extensions as it seemed like the most straight forward thing to do for me. I would love if anyone could direct me to a tutorial maybe where they have done something similar. I want the browser to refresh till element is present then proceed once it is. Also does anyone know if i can use the image tag as the element it needs to wait for?